# How to find and extract table from Excel file with random position

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel files with table. I know how to get data with C# if table position(col and row of first cell) is fixed but problem is that before that table could be some heder with random content and size. I need somehow skip header and find position of table. What could be best solution for that task.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the contents of the Excel file we can't possibly answer this for you. Iterate through the rows until you find what you're looking for I guess? Mark the table in the Excel document for easy locating? How would you answer this question if all you had to go on was what you've provided?

Comment: the problem is that I don't initially know column name or data could be. all I can think of is that data table should have lots of columns > 100 and data in each column should be same (for example col1 - guids, col2 - numbers, col3 - dates).

Answer (score 0):

A table is a ListObject, You can find out where it is by going through the ListObjects.  You can then access the DataBodyRange to get the address of the table contents.

in C#

```
    public void GetTableAddress(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject lObj in ws.ListObjects)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lObj.DataBodyRange.Address);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ws.ListObjects returns nothing for excel files with data.

Comment: @AlexKapelyukhovskiy  then they are not formatted as tables.